# While Loop Response & Look File

Tags: python, file, loops, while-loop

I have been at a two day loss trying to figure something out (probably due to my limited ability coding) Usgin Python 3.4.1

I am trying to design a series of options for an input and have option "4" be the pass but only if a file is present in specific location. I can press any number anytime and it repeats. However if I select 4 and the file is not present it comes back with Incorrect but no matter the next answer it continues my program.

```
print ("Please Choose From the Following Options")
print ("1. Option A")
print ("2. Option B")
print ("3. Option C")
print ("4. Option D")
print ("5. Option R")
monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")

monkey = "4"

while monkey != monkeyGuess:
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")

while monkey == monkeyGuess:
    try:
        with open('c:\test.txt') as file:
            break
            pass
    except IOError as e:
        time.sleep(1)
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")
```

I tired combing the two and with little results:

```
while monkey != monkeyGuess:
    time.sleep(1)
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect Inputs Found")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")
    monkey == monkeyGuess or os.path.isfile('test.txt') 
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect Inputs Found")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach doesn't work because once the correct input (`4`) has been entered, the first `while` loop has been passed, and all the user has to do to bypass the second loop is to pick a wrong input, because then `while monkey == monkeyGuess` will be `False` and the loop will stop.

The second approach is missing an `if` statement, but even if it had one, all the user needs to do is to make `while monkey != monkeyGuess:` `False` by picking the correct number - whether or not the file exists doesn't matter.

---

Solution:

```
print ("Please Choose From the Following Options")
print ("1. Option A")
print ("2. Option B")
print ("3. Option C")
print ("4. Option D")
print ("5. Option R")

monkey = "4"

while True:
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")

    if monkeyGuess != monkey:
        print ()
        print ("Incorrect")
        continue

    try:
        with open('c:\test.txt') as file:
            break
    except IOError as e:
        print ()
        print ("Incorrect")
```

Generally, a `while True` loop is best suited for this scenario. Ask for user input inside the loop, and then `break` out of the loop using `if` statements.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you so much I was just trying to read up on while Ture statements last night at 3 am and just couldn't wrap my head around it. This works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the version of python you are running this code with:

```
bash-3.2$ touch test.txt #Creates a file there so we can ignore the line that checks if it exists
bash-3.2$ python2.7 monkey.py #This is where the script is
Please Choose From the Following Options
1. Option A
2. Option B
3. Option C
4. Option D
5. Option R
Selection: 4
()
Incorrect
Selection: ^C
bash-3.2$ python3.4 monkey.py #Using python3.4
Please Choose From the Following Options
1. Option A
2. Option B
3. Option C
4. Option D
5. Option R
Selection: 4
bash-3.2$ #It exits fine
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: I am sorry but very new to all of this and you lost me on your code. This is 100% different then anything I have seen. So your saying to stop using while?

Comment: No, @CipherBlue, sorry for being confusing :) When you run your python script, do you call `python myscript.py` in the shell? If not, what do you type in to run your code?

Comment: :) no problem, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: Nope I was running the wrong test. I have not got it still thought I did.

Comment: OK, how are you running your program?

Comment: I tired this and oddly sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it doesnt (I realize that doesnt make sense but when I delete the file it seems to still think its there)

while monkey != monkeyGuess:
    time.sleep(1)
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect Inputs Found")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")
    monkey == monkeyGuess or os.path.isfile('test.txt') 
    print ()
    print ("Incorrect Inputs Found")
    monkeyGuess = input("Selection: ")

Comment: I am using Pythons native system and 
import time
import sys
import ctypes
import os
import os.path